# PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, relational-database

I wrote this procedure 'TT1_ajoute_person_dans_album' to insert the OID of album row  in the nested table of column 'album' in the table 'personnage'

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE TT1_ajoute_person_dans_album(pnum IN NUMBER,anum IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT ALBUMS from TT1_PERSONNAGE_TABLE  where NUMP=pnum) 
values (SELECT REF(a) from TT1_ALBUM_TABLE a where a.NUMA=anum);
   COMMIT;
 END TT1_ajoute_person_dans_album;
```

Those are the objects:

```
Create Type TT1_Album_Type As Object(NumA Number, Titre Varchar(50), Annee_Pub Number, Album_Suiv Varchar(50));

Create Type TT1_Album_NT_Type As Table OF REF TT1_Album_Type ;
Create Type TT1_Personnage_Type As Object(NumP Number, Nom Varchar(40), Prenom Varchar(40), Profession varchar(50), Sexe Varchar(1), Genre Varchar(20), albums TT1_Album_NT_Type);
```

But a message appeared 
    `ERROR at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression`

What's wrong?

Comment: Huh?  The insert statement is really messed-up.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd edit your question and include the definitions of `TT1_PERSONNAGE_TABLE` and `TT1_ALBUM_TABLE`. Thanks.

Comment: @OldProgrammer From the syntax section of your link go to [`insert_into_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2121694) > [`DML_table_expression_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2126242) > [`table_collection_expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2121871) and you will find the syntax there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for inserting into a nested table is `INSERT INTO TABLE( subquery ) VALUES ( values )`. However, the sub-query has the syntax `( SELECT nested_table_column FROM table_name WHERE ... )` and so, noting the parenthesis around the sub-query, you will need to have two sets of parentheses. The same applies for the `VALUES` clause:

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE TT1_ajoute_person_dans_album(
  pnum IN NUMBER,
  anum IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE(
    ( SELECT ALBUMS FROM TT1_PERSONNAGE_TABLE WHERE NUMP=pnum )
  ) VALUES (
    ( SELECT REF(a) FROM TT1_ALBUM_TABLE a WHERE a.NUMA=anum )
  );
  COMMIT;
END TT1_ajoute_person_dans_album;
/
```

Also, are you really sure you want to issue a `COMMIT` in the procedure? If you have multiple procedures which each contain commits and one fails you will not be able to rollback all of them.